# First Order Differential Equation for a Harmonic Oscillator

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

A box with mass $m$ is attached to a spring with spring coefficient $k$. This system is then placed into a glass case filled with a liquid with drag coefficient $\alpha$.

Now I have the following equation set-up:

$m\ddot{x}+\alpha\dot{x}+kx=0$

Now the solution for this is with usage of $e^\left(\lambda t\right)$, but what I would like to know is when to use exponent and when to use $Acos(\omega t +\phi)$?

Also, the frequency is $\omega=\sqrt\frac{k}{m} $ is that just by dividing the coefficient of $"\ddot{x}"$ term and the coefficient of the "x" term?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need two small edits as there is no clear $c$ term in your differential equations and your $\alpha$ appears to have been changed to an $a$.

Comment: If I remember correctly, since $e^{i \theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$, the usage between $e^{(\lambda t)}$ and $\cos \theta$ can be interchanged as much as you want. 
$$$$
As for your second question, yes. If you solve the second order differential equation ($-kx = m \ddot x; \alpha = 0$) you'd get $\omega = \sqrt{\frac km}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to extend upon Aldon's comment on the first part.

It is important to distinguish between the two situations $\alpha >0$ and $\alpha = 0$. If there is friction, i.e. if $\alpha>0$, then the box will ultimately be at rest. This can only be captured by using the exponential form. Observe that the characteristic equation 
\begin{equation}
m z^2 + \alpha z + k = 0
\end{equation}
has the two roots $\lambda = \frac{-\alpha \pm \sqrt{\alpha^2 - 4 km}}{2m}$. The real parts are negative, stressing the exponential decay. On the other hand if $\alpha=0$, then the box will swing happily back and forth until the end of time and the harmonic form is sufficient. The phase shift $\phi$ is needed to accommodate specific initial conditions.

I have nothing to add to the second part beyond what Aldon has already written in the comments.